# Google Apps Script - Deploy as web app - now requires me to "Share" the the code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I recently made a simple change to an google app script - once I re-deployed, you can access whichever page is in the:

var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('my1');

But any subsequent attempts to open a different html page by clicking a button with a link, will display "Google Drive - Access Denied" /  "Google Drive, You need permission..."

I tested also, by creating a VERY simple web app, that does not attemp to access any google 'sheets', drive, or any other API, and get the same result - is the "Publish - Deploy as web app" broken?

Comment: Can you please post your web app link ? What have you selected in "Execute as" while deploying the web app

Comment: Have the same issue. When I share project user can see web service.
`
Run as: my user,
Who has access: Everybody from company
`

Comment: I have opened an "Issue" in Issue Tracker [77884956](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77884956)...  This has all the code and comments from others that have seen the same issue.  It has been added to the "HotList"...

Comment: Keep in mind the code I posted was just a simple example to show them that the issue is not with some API, it happens on all scripts.  The example simply uses the "ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()" function which appears to be the issue that requires you to share the code...

Comment: To answer Umair...  I "Publish" -> "Deloy as web app..." -> "Execute the app as: Me"... -> "Who has access to the app: Anyone within xxxxxx.com"  -  I even tried to allow access to "Anyone even anonymous" - same result...

Comment: Well, they must have made a change somewhere, it now works without having to share your code...  it would be nice to know what they (google) changed...